# Can you access the shadow dom from a script inside the shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

Can you access the shadow dom from within a script inside the shadow dom?

Here's a dumb example of the kind of code I might want. Not sure I'm a fan of Chrome's extension for declarative shadow Dom but it's useful for the example.

Open shadow Dom might be the simplest option but it's still annoying.

```
<div>
<template shadowroot="closed">
<script type="module" src="menu.mjs"></script>

<div id="summary">
  <slot name="menu"></slot>
  <button id="menu-button">Open</button>
</div>
<div id="details">
<slot></slot>
</div>
</template>

<h2 slot="menu">Menu</h2>

<a>Home</a>
<a>Search</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Why is ``open``annoying? The whole point of ``closed`` is to close the cookie jar and keep _all_ prying fingers out.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman but the script is already inside the cookie jar! You can put a style element inside a shadow Dom to access it so why not a script?

Comment: Doesn't the script run in window/document scope?